# twitter bootstrap typeahead source from mysql/JSON

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

So basically, I want my my typeahead to get source from mysql table.

Below is my code:

```
 <script src="../../js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var patients = [HERE I WANT TO PUT THE SUGGEST_PATIENTS.PHP];
       $('#search_bar').typeahead({source: patients})

 </script>
```

suggest_patient.php

```
 <?php
include('../../db.php');

       $query = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM patients WHERE fname LIKE ?');
       $query->execute(array('value%'));

           $output_string = '';

           for($i=0; $row = $query->fetch(); $i++){
                $fname = $row['fname'];
                $lname = $row['lname'];
                $mname = $row['mname'];
                $bday = $row['bday'];
                $religion = $row['religion'];
                $occupation = $row['occupation'];
                $gender = $row['gender'];
                $phoneno = $row['phoneno'];
                $address = $row['address'];
                $type = $row['type'];    
           }

           $output_string = $fname;
      echo json_encode($output_string);
 ?>
```

But it's not getting the typeahead effect. Can you please help me figure out what's missing in my code? Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) it states that the `source` should be an array or a javascript function.

Comment: Hi thanks for pointing me there, but I've updated my question, I want to pass JSON to my javascript variable patients.

Comment: You will need to load the php file with ajax or include it with php, however I still don't think this will work as source should be **array** or **function** not json.

Comment: for JSON I know how to convert it to array.

Comment: it would be better to include it with php just do `<?php include 'SUGGEST_PATIENTS.PHP' ?>`. If you want to do it with ajax though, look at the [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation.